# Storing an OS X App's path inside a custom environment variable

Tags: macos, environment-variables

OS X starts an application bundle executable from an "unpredictable" working directory (depending on OS X version, it can be /, ~, application bundle root, or something else). Is there a way to "capture" the actual location of the executable on the file system and save it inside the application's Info.plist, for later use (via LSEnvironment maybe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one way I found this could be done: have the executable from inside the bundle launched not directly, but via a script that sets up the necessary environment variables. This script should be able to tell its own location.

Modifying anything inside the bundle, as I was suggesting above, is a big no no, as it would break the signed code and Gatekeeper would flag this behavior.